# Reinstall Ruby on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos

I've gone and messed up Ruby on my Snow Leopard Machine. I've managed to introduce all sorts of issues and I'm having a hard time cleaning things up.

What are the steps to get me back to square one with Ruby? I'm fairly new to programming so I need it spelled out for me!

Comment: What exactly did you mess up?

Comment: That's a good question...I'm not actually sure. I went willy nilly installing gems and upgrading stuff and god knows what else. I get errors all over the place when I tried to even start thin. I spent a long time googling to no avail so I just want to start fresh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like what you probably want to do is clear out all your globally installed gems in the system Ruby. This can be done by running the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/*
```

This will leave all the gems that come with OS X (which is a good thing, since some apps may assume they're installed).

As macarthy said, I also highly recommend using a Ruby version manager (e.g. [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/)) to more easily install, remove, and manage Ruby versions.

Comment: I actually tried this to no avail, I;ll be trying to RVM approach for sure

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to forget about what you have and use RVM

- https://rvm.io

you can basically ignore what you have installed then.

Comment: I've been reading good things about RVM and intend to use it. One thing I'm unsure of is how I make my ruby apps use the RVM installed ruby instead of what I already had. I actually thought I needed to clean my crap up before I could use RVM.

Comment: RVM installs ruby into a different place, and then alters your path (when asked to) so the `ruby` command points to the version you specify. You can use a project level `.rvmrc` file to set which ruby you want used for a particular project. More information here: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: No need. Basically yours shell or webserver is where you specify which ruby is used. Happens automatically with your shell , (after your set the default), in passenger you set it in your conf files. Per project you can add a dot file in the project root

Comment: @macarthy and @Colin, This won't fix the problem. Apple installs Ruby for their use. We can piggy back on it, but screwing it up means Apple's code that calls Ruby won't work. Use `find /usr -name '*.rb' -type f` to see some of what uses it. Using RVM doesn't repair the damage to the system Ruby, nor does it provide a way for the system code to run if it needs to.

Comment: How, then, can one repair the OS X's Ruby?